# Docker prerelease setting and ROS Indigo incompatible?

Tags: ros, ubuntu, pre-release, docker, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[New way of prerelease introduced upon Jade release](http://wiki.ros.org/regression_tests#How_do_I_setup_my_system_to_run_a_prerelease.3F) requires some python3 packages, such as following to my knowledge, which uninstalls so many packages on my Trusty machine so that ROS Indigo (and perhaps Jade too) becomes unusable. How can I use this method while I keep using Indigo?

```
python3-ros-buildfarm, python3-catkin-pkg, python3-rosdistro, python3-ros-buildfarm, python3-rospkg
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/210233/docker-prerelease-setting-and-ros-indigo-incompatible?/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2015-05-30

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran into this as well. Instead of python3-ros-buildfarm, just install python-ros-buildfarm.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2015-05-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2015-05-30**:
I updated the wiki page.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2015-06-25**:
I just tested this too, works for me.